# CAPTCHA and time counter scripts

Tags: noscript, ip-address

When I access a download site such as *depositfiles*, I have to enable scripts for the download to take place. The scripts are: Re-CAPTCHA and a time counter for about a minute, the download is only available after the countdown is finished. Do these scripts enable the site to see my IP address? I checked the download link, and it shows the Tor server's IP address, not mine.

Answer (score 1):

No, these scripts most likely will not enable the site to see your IP address, but they can figure out the following information about you:

1. You are using Tor network and your IP address is a Tor exit node.
2. You are a human and not a robot. Robots still do not have enough artificial intelligence to act as humans in these type of tests. (but in near future they may be able to pass these type of tests).
3. They may be able to run scripts to obtain other relevant information about your computer(hardware), and your software(your operating system, your fonts, etc.).
4. They may pay special attention to you, if you make any misstep and disclose any information inadvertently, they may take advantage of that to de-anonymise you.